Setting up DNS Records for Mail Sever
I need some help with DNS Records. I'm trying to setup a mail server on my NAS. For my domain registrar under DNS Records since I already own a domain name from this registrar. I create a subdomain name for the DNS Records, set its content to [subdomain].[domain].ca
set its type to MX and the name to @.
Although after three days that sub-domain did not propagate on the internet; as well, it did not show up under my domain registrar DNS records either ?
I also wanted to know, must I create a DNS Record with a Name of MX and its type set to A with the IP address pointing to my NAS which will host the mail server ?

If it it did not show up under your domain registrar DNS records, then where did you actually create it?

DNS & Nameservers > Add DNS Records in my registrar.

So you added the DNS records and then they disappeared from the same section? Or are you talking about two different places?

I added the DNS Record, then you could say; they disappeared from the same area.

That sounds like an issue with the registrar's DNS hosting service specifically, not a DNS problem in general? Do the records keep disappearing after you add them again? (Though the records you've described aren't correct, but they shouldn't disappear by themselves.)

How should the record be written especially for an MX record ? If I know what I'm doing wrong when doing the record even though there isn't much to enter in for the record. I may be able to inform the registrar of the issue why it keeps disappearing.

The contents should have no effect on it disappearing; it's not the DNS hosting service's job to validate the records. But, are you planning to receive mail at ***@domain.ca or at ***@subdomain.domain.ca?

I want to retrieve mail at ***@subdomain.domain.ca

Okay, and do you currently have any records with A <nas_ip>? Does the base domain or any subdomain point to your NAS external address?

I don't have any records pointing to A <nas_ip>
The base domain does not point to my NAS external address and no subdomain points to my NAS external address, as no subdomain exist.
